# error invalid conversion from const char* to int

Tags: c++

I am getting an error error invalid conversion from const char* to int. I understand what the error is but i don't know how to fix it. Any help appreciated.

The error is in the line:

BigNum temp = str.c_str();

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, BigNum& bignum)
  {
    string str;
    is >> str;
    BigNum temp = str.c_str();
    bignum = temp;
    return is;
  }
```

Comment: Since you haven't said what `BigNum` is it's going to be hard to help.

Comment: Why exactly do you think you should be able to assign a pointer to that type of object?

Comment: @user3403896 How the constructor of BigNum is defined.

Answer (score 1):

.... You're assigning a string to be a BigNum. Why are you doing that?

C++ does not let you implicitly convert between integers and pointers, if that's what you're attempting to do.

C++ is also not the kind of language where you can just assign a string to an int and have it convert, if that is what you're trying to do. You'll need to do some form of `lexical_cast`ing.

Comment: If the `BigNum` class has an overloaded assignment operator that takes a string pointer or a constructor that takes a string pointer, then yes, you can assign a string the a `BigNum`

Comment: Sure, but usually a BigNum is something like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/32041/). Essentially a duplication of a python int's 'infinite precision'.

Comment: Sure, but usually a BigNum is something like https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.  Essentially a C or C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the compiler could not find:
1. An overloaded assignment operator containing a `char *` parameter or
2. A `BigNum` constructor that takes a `char *`.

I suggest to add the assignment operator for `std::string`.  You may also need a constructor and copy constructor that take an `std::string` parameter.

Search the web for "C++ rule of three".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you need is to convert object str of type `std::string` to an object of type int and call the corresponding constructor.

Try the following

```
BigNum temp( stoi( str ) );
```

or if the constructor is not explicit then

```
BigNum temp = stoi( str );
```

instead of

```
BigNum temp = str.c_str();
```